# Tutorial for building single exe for Qt

Tags: qt, static, executable

So I want to find a tutorial that teach how to build single EXE using Qt.
i use mingw and windeployqt for deployment (still some dll is missing and i manually copy them) then it works.

But i do not understand the steps in https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows

It indicated to build static version of Qt.

```
> configure -static -release -no-exceptions
> mingw32-make sub-src
```

But where do i type this at? When I open Cmd prompt and type it immediately, it just say "configure" is not recognized as an internal or external command....

Does this mean I need to close Qt Creator, build a "static" version of Qt Creator and then run a static version of Qt Creator? It is very confusing for me. Apologies cause I am new to this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to develop an executable program (console or windows application) or you want to make an installer for your already developed application?

Comment: In order to use configure from command line, you need to start Qt Command Prompt

Comment: I want to make single .exe for my widget application. normal build will have many files together. i want to pack all into 1 app.exe only. is this possible?

Comment: This means you need to compile static build of Qt Framework, then use this static version to build your static application.  Maybe this youtube video helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwX_urJJOf8

Comment: Thanks @Xplatforms i will look at video.

Comment: Okay I understand, you want to link statically instead of having to distribute qt dlls. Indeed, I didn't do this before with qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have mingw, perl and python in your path. Download Qt source zip of your choice from [here](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/). Extract zip to the file system, e.g. C:\src\

Now you open a command prompt, go into the Qt source root and run configure and make from there.

```
cd C:\src\qt-<something>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php to create an installer and use qt dll instead to build an exe with qt static libraries.